# How to load multiple image in openCV one by one?

Tags: python

I have a question on about OpenCV when using `imread()`
I had successfully parse my path into a list
When running the function it will show as below `TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'`

here is my code that show me the above error
*some code i have to cover up due to privacy

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import glob

def parse_folder(path):
    images = glob.glob(f'{path}/*.jpg') + glob.glob(f'{path}/*.png')
    return images
path = "D:\\Path\\to\\100+images"
images = parse_folder(path)

def image_to_text(image_path):
    # Opening the image & storing it in an image object
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    *the rest of the code*

arr_data = image_to_text(images)
```

parsing the whole folder path is fine

i'm able to see all the images in the list
Is there something that i'm not familiar with the `imread()` method ?

Comment: Why don't you read the docs for imread?

Answer (score 1):

```
all_images = [cv2.imread(each_file) for each_file in list_of_image_paths]
```

Use these collected images(numpy arrays) and process one by one.

Please refer [cv2.imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.imread` loads a single file, not a list of files.

you can use a for loop to load images.

```
def image_to_text(image_path):
    # Opening the image & storing it in an image object
    for file in image_path:
        img = cv2.imread(file)
        *do something with the single image*
```

You can load all images at once and store in a list, however it might not be a good idea if #images is large.

Comment: i tried with looping all the file , but it only show me 1 output instead of all the array , my images have a total of 270 images, is there a way to load and process 1 image at a time ?

Comment: if `image_path` is a list of valid image paths, then the above code should read 1 image at a time. From you function name `image_to_text`, I think you are trying to run some OCR on the image. May be you forgot to append your results to list or a dict.